# Export Material View OBJ for Reality Converter

Tags: materials, uv, objects, export, conversion

Is there a way in Blender to directly export exactly what is displayed in the Materials View as a .obj file? I'm trying to load the file into Apple's Reality Converter with the material attached because it never shows up in the finished USDZ file.